# Manipulating an ordered Hash in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

i have the following query that returns an ordered hash

```
counts = VideoLog.count(
    :conditions =>["question_id = ? AND user_id = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ? AND dashboard = ? AND watched = ?", video.id,current_user.id, @start_date, @end_date, "#{@dashboard}", 1],
    :group      => "created_at"
  )
```

counts is an ordered hash:

```
{Wed Nov 30 07:37:36 UTC 2011=>1, Fri Nov 18 11:01:05 UTC 2011=>1, Wed Nov 30 07:38:16 UTC 2011=>1}
```

and i wanna modify it's indexes to a specific timezone and then convert them to date only and then iterate over them, how do i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what you want to do with the repeated keys, I assumed that you want to sum them. So:

```
h = {"Wed Nov 30 07:37:36 UTC 2011"=>1, "Fri Nov 18 11:01:05 UTC 2011"=>1, "Wed Nov 30 07:38:16 UTC 2011"=>1}

h.inject(Hash.new 0) do |res, pair|
  res[Time.parse(pair.first).in_time_zone("Europe/Paris").to_date] += pair.last; res
end
```

and the result is

```
=> {Wed, 30 Nov 2011=>2, Fri, 18 Nov 2011=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
counts.each do |key,value|
    key = Date.parse key.localtime("+12:00").to_s
    # do something
end
```